# "Let's get you going on looking for those journals then." A librarian says this to give a student assistance

Tags: meaning-in-context, causative-get

A librarian says this to give a student assistance.

> Let's **get** you going on looking for those journals then.

Does "get" mean "make" or "start"?

I looked up two different meanings in the dictionary.

- to make, persuade in Entry 17 [Source](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get)
- start in Entry 18. [Source](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get)

My thought on this is that "go on" means "continue". So I think the meaning "make" is suitable in this situation.

Do you have any thought on that?

Comment: It's like _get him talking_ in No. 17, with the sense 'cause/help you to start'.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh The layout looks clear, thx.

Comment: [Get going](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+going) is its own idiom.

Comment: I happen to realise that No.17 has an implicit meaning of 'to start'. It is unlike No. 18 which has explicit or obvious meaning of 'to start'. Although both share the same sense in that.